# Spring Integration webservices jms

Tags: web-services, jms, spring-integration

I am new with spring integration and I wanna apply it between 3 applications which are online banking app, core banking app, third party webservice. the idea is to expose pay bill service from the online banking app.

firstly, I wanna build a bus between the three applications. online application should connect to the bus through http, core banking through jms, and the third party also through http.

secondly, the following is the scenario I looking for:
online banking send request to core  banking through the bus and wait the response then the core banking will check the balance of the client if it covers then call the third party webservices and pay the bill then reply with success to the online banking otherwise reply with error to the online banking.

I never mind changing the scenario. I just wanna apply spring integration on those 3 applications.

Comment: What you describe is correct and valid use-case for Spring Integration. What is not clear here where is the question? What made you to come to us here? Also that's too broad what you say here. You question is going to be closed.

Comment: my question was how to do that, but someone told me today spring integration will not gonna help in request/response communication like the case of online banking call core banking and wait until core banking to call the third party to validate the bill and complete the transaction then response with success or failure (based on the situation) to the online banking.

Comment: Spring Integration can help in most business cases. There is definitely a request/response components, there is an aggregator, router and so on. Nevertheless `How to do that?` is not so simple to answer. That's the request to implement a solution for you - not the way this forum works...